# What to do when findViewById cannot find a GUI resource while debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Spent about an hour on this so I thought I'd save somebody else the trouble. Using Eclipse 3.6.2.

My call to findViewById a GUI widget keep returning null. Check the code and xml over and over and over, no problems. Finally exited and restarted Eclipse and suddenly findViewById worked.

Comment: lol. When nothing works, just restart!

Answer (score 0):

The next time you can just delete the R.java file, and let Eclipse regenerate it, then it should work too.

Comment: It's a bug with ADT 10. The R.java generates find, but the resource is not optimized and packaged in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I find I have been needing to do Project > Clean when adding a new resource. If I simply tell it to build, the R.java will regenerate, but the resource will not be optimized and packaged in the bundle. Chalk it up to an Android bug and remember to clean.